# How to populate an Object[] with items

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use a Swing Dialog so that the user can choose an item from a list of options with poolTeams being the name of that list. Like this:

`String team = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please choose a team:\n",
    "Choose Team", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, poolTeams, "");`

According to the documentation, poolTeams needs to be of type Object[] so I can't use ArrayLists or anything like that.

The problem is; the items in poolTeams will vary so I can't just populate it like
`Object[] poolTeams = {"a", "b", "c"};`

Is there a way I can make the program populate it automatically? If not, is there a different way I can offer the user a list in the dialog box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Object> options = new ArrayList<Object>();

options.add(...);
options.add(...);
options.add(...);
Object [] selections = options.toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily turn an ArrayList to an array using the toArray() method. Build up your ArrayList, then turn it into an array when you need it.